# Route between Durham, NC and Carrboro, NC?

Tags: bikeroutes

I've been googling around (Strava, mapmyride, local bike shops) and I couldn't find a recommended bike route between Durham and Carrboro (or Chapel Hill for that matter). If [google map's](https://goo.gl/maps/M15xnAk8dDR2) suggestion is the best, that's fine, but it would be helpful for someone whose done it to corroborate.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this for commute or recreation?

Comment: It's for recreation

Comment: what do you mean by "recommended"? recommended by whom?

Comment: Recommended by someone who is familiar with the area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you want to start or finish, but here's some strava routes for central Durham to to central Carrboro

Red roads are more popular for cyclists, blue ones are less travelled, and white ones are rarely or never cycled.

[image: popular]
[Route between Durham, NC and Carrboro, NC?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34984/route-between-durham-nc-and-carrboro-nc)   This one is the most "popular" based on strava tracks, and is 22.8 km.

[image: elevation]
This path minimises elevation changes, so instead of 309 metres of vertical you only have 225 metres of climbs.

[image: direct]
This is the most direct path but it appears to go down a main road, which may not be legal on a bike, in your area.

You can also find a number of strava segments in the area, using this link
https://www.strava.com/segments/explore#location/durham/type/cycling/min/0/max/5/surface/undefined/center/35.92059,-79.052797/zoom/14/map_type/terrain

Curiously, Google's suggestion is different again to any of these.

Answer (score 1):

I've never been there, but as a routing tool I can recommend brouter.org.

I find Google maps often doesn't know about a lot of paths, and still tries to direct you down major roads even when they are not the shortest way. Personally I prefer a quiet road to a major road, even if the road has a cycle path.

The maps are detailed and the profiles can be customized extensively.

Link: http://brouter.de/brouter-web/